# Create Variable Based on Conditions from an Array

Tags: pandas

I have this

| ID | name | pos | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Dan | QB | MIA |
| 001 | Eric | WR | DEN |
| 001 | Stan | TE | MIA |
| 002 | Chad | TE | PHI |
| 002 | Dan | QB | MIA |
| 002 | Bill | WR | MIA |

and I need to turn it into this

| ID | name | pos | team | QB/TE | QB/WR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Dan | QB | MIA | 1 | 0 |
| 001 | Eric | WR | DEN | 1 | 0 |
| 001 | Stan | TE | MIA | 1 | 0 |
| 002 | Chad | TE | PHI | 0 | 1 |
| 002 | Dan | QB | MIA | 0 | 1 |
| 002 | Bill | WR | MIA | 0 | 1 |

I'm attempting to create a binary variable that is a '1' when QB and TE are from the same team and have the same ID.

What's the best way to create a condition based on values in an array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's really hard to understand what you're trying to achieve my friend. What "QB/TE" means? What function you're trying to apply?

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Should have explained further - editing now.  

Attempting to create a binary variable where all rows that are part of the same ID have a '1' if QB and TE are from the same team.

I'm just not sure which function to use since I'm creating a binary variable based on rows that are part of a group.  

Thank you for pointing that out!